# Как найти заданное пользователем число в массиве?

Tags: java

/** Returns the index of the first occurrence of the array element with the given value.

- The search for the element is started at the given start index to the end of the array.
- @param a  an integer array
- @param begin  the index in the array, where to start the search (begin included)
- @param value  an integer value to be searched in the array
  *
- @return   the index of the first element with the given value, -1 if value could
- not be found

static int getPosition(int[] a, int begin, int value)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

int n;
System.out.println("Введите длину Массива");

n = SavitchIn.readInt();
int [] test = new int [n];


for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){ // запустили все индексы

test[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*100000)); //все числа в массиве могут быть рандомными

getPosition(test, 3351 ,65732); /* потом мы должны протестить
функцию  и если в нашем массиве 
Test оказывается 3351 или же 65732,
то функция должна вывести или вернуть 
позицию на котором находятся эти цифры*/
}

пример

 test [3, 1, 10, 7, 9] 
getPosition(test, 2, 9) returns 4 - в данном случае на 4 позиции 
getPosition(test, 0, 5) returns -1 - если же такого числа нет в массиве.


Заранее всем благодарен за любую помощь!))
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему комментарию к строке `getPosition(test, 3351, 65732);`, вы неправильно поняли назначение второго аргумента.

3351 - это не одно из искомых чисел, а индекс элемента массива с которого следует начинать поиск (@param begin the index in the array, where to start the search (begin included)).

А метод getPosition() будет выглядеть так:

```
public class FemaleLogic {

    static int getPosition(int[] a, int begin, int value) {
        for (int i = begin; i < a.length; i++) {
            // если элемент найден, возвращается его индекс
            if (a[i] == value) return i; 
        }
        return -1; // если элемент не найден, возвращается -1
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args){
        int[] arr = {5, 8, 6, 23, 1, 9, 4, 7, 8, 2, 5};
        System.out.println(getPosition(arr, 0, 23));
        System.out.println(getPosition(arr, 5, 23));
    }
}
```

Результат:

3

-1